# Strange integer comparison in C

Tags: c, comparison, boolean

I am writing simple program in C and I can't see why:

```
printf("%d\n", 1 == 1 == 1);
printf("%d\n", 1 == 1);
printf("%d\n", 0 == 0 == 0);
printf("%d\n", 0 == 0);
```

Gives:

```
1
1
0
1
```

I'm used to Python so all this is new and strange to me.

(As an aside who was the inventor?)

Comment: Nothing strange here apart from the poorly parenthesised expressions.  First law of programming - break the problem (in this case the expressions) down into bits that are small enough for you to understand.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dennis_Ritchie was the inventor

Answer (score 12):

> I think C is for aliens, not humans.

Maybe. No human would write code as `1 == 1 == 1`.

Anyway, what's going on here. The expression gets parsed AFAIK as `(1 == 1) == 1`, so it's a comparison of a result of another comparison with 1. Truth values are represented as integers in C; true is 1, false is 0. So `1 == 1` is 1 (true) and that is equal to 1.

With `0 == 0 == 0`, it's similar:

```
(0 == 0) == 0
1 == 0 // 0 == 0 is true (1)
0 // 1 == 0 is false (0)
```

Comment: It was just a test. I wanted to check if a == b == true (1). And I am a human... I think.

Comment: 1 == 1 == 1 can be evaluated either as `(1 == 1) == 1` or `1 == (1 == 1)` and _you cannot know which that applies_. This is called "order of evaluation" and which one that applies is unspecified behavior.

Comment: @marcinpz: What you need I guess is `if((a==b)&&(b==1))`

Comment: Yes. Now I have `if( (0 == strcmp(...)) && (0 == strcmp(..)) )`. And It is ok, but previously I've tested `(0 == strcmp(...) == strcmp(...))` which didn't worked as I expected.

Comment: @Lundin You are confusing the syntactic concept of precedence with the dynamic concept of order of evaluation. The associativity of `1 == 1 == 1` is perfectly defined by e.g. C99 6.5.9:1. Undefined behavior is not involved.

Comment: @Complicatedseebio: Umm... no? I'm not sure what you found in 6.5.9/1 that has anything to do with this? Also I said it was _unspecified_ behavior, not undefined, which is quite a difference.  See 6.5/3: `Except as specified later (for the function-call (), &&, ||, ?:, and comma operators), the order of evaluation of subexpressions and the order in which side effects take place are both unspecified.`

Comment: @Lundin Here is a derivation of the AST `(1 == 1) == 1` using the grammar of C99 6.5.9:1. E → E == R → (E == R) == R. How do you derive `1 == (1 == 1)` in a way that is compatible with that grammar? PS: yes, you said "unspecified" and it is indeed quite different, sorry.

Comment: @Lundin On the same page as 6.5:3, as part of footnote 72, there is the sentence "Within each major subclause, the operators have the same precedence. Left- or right-associativity is 
indicated in each subclause by the syntax for the expressions discussed therein."

Comment: @Complicatedseebio ??? That grammar describes the relation between the relational operators and the equality operators. What has that to do with _anything_?

Comment: @Lundin That grammar indicates the left- or right-associativity of the operator `==` by only allowing you to derive the AST `(1 == 1) == 1` from the concrete syntax `1 == 1 == 1`. Please read footnote 72. Alternately, try and fail to derive `1 == (1 == 1)` if that is more convincing for you.

Answer (score 3):

You need to understand

1. Operator precedence (http://www.swansontec.com/sopc.html).
2. That in C / C++ 0 is equivalent to false and any non zero integer is equivalent to true.
3. The bool type is implicitly castable as an integer with 0 casting to false and 1 casting to true.

Thus `1 == 1 == 1` is evaluated as `(1 == 1) == 1` --> `true == 1` --> `true`. Whence `printf("%d\n", 1 == 1 == 1)` --> `printf("%d\n", true)` --> `printf("%d\n", (int)true)` --> `printf("%d\n", 1)` --> `1`

Comment: Operator presedence has nothing to do with this question. 1 == 1 == 1 can be evaluated either as `(1 == 1) == 1` or `1 == (1 == 1)` and _you cannot know which that applies_. This is called "order of evaluation" and which one that applies is unspecified behavior.

Comment: @Lundin Sorry to repeat myself, but you have it backwards. This example has everything to do with precedence and nothing to do with order of evaluation.

Comment: @Complicatedseebio How did you come to the conclusion that operator precedence matters in an expression that only uses one kind of operator, namely `==`? If you look in the standard or one of the usual precedence tables, you will surely find the `==` operator at the very same line as the `==` operator...

Answer (score 2):

The result of the `==` operator is `1` if the two operands have the same value and `0` if the two values are different.